# Is the value of a variable always guaranteed to be 1 word away from the variable created outside of scope if it comes immediately after?

Tags: c++, memory, language-lawyer

```
int main()
{
    {int x = 532;}
    int xc;
    int x = *(&xc+1);
    cout << x << endl; // prints 532
}
```

I create an int variable with a value of 532 and then it immediately goes out of scope.
I then create another int variable right after so that it has an address of 1 word before x.
I then assign that value of whatever was one word past xc to x and print it, and it has the value of 532.
Is this guaranteed to happen? Why/why not?

Comment: There is no word in C++.

Comment: [I get zero at optimization level 0](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cxPbbvfYT), and [41988848 at optimization level 1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YqrzWfMY8), so clearly there is no guarantee.

Comment: A variable doesn't have to be in memory at all.  [Observe this assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/7EsaEYqvr).

Comment: `&xc+1` is a pointer past `xc`. You are not allowed to dereference it at all. Doing that causes already undefined behavior. Individual variables do not have any memory relation to one another at all, except that they do not overlap while in their lifetime / during their storage duration.

Comment: Short answer: no. Your code has undefined behaviour, due to dereferencing `(&xc + 1)`, so anything can happen.  The relationship of addresses of any two `int`s with distinct declarations is unspecified by the standard.   In fact, a compiler is permitted to optimise all of the variables in your code entirely out of existence, and simply emit code to output a junk value.  (It is also permitted to reformat your hard drive - such is the nature of undefined behaviour).

Comment: It's very interesting. If you change the offset to try and make it match, the address of xc also changes at compile time so it's always 4 away. If you don't dereference it though, it matches up. If you dereference it and then print out the address it also matches up, but as soon as you comment out the line that prints the address of x, it doesn't match up again. The compiler is doing some very weird optimizations or checks. @RaymondChen

Comment: As the saying goes, "Play stupid games, win stupid prizes."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the arrangement and padding (and even the existence) of variables on the stack is implementation-dependent, and what you have here is Undefined Behavior. The language specifies that you must not use a pointer to access the memory of any object other than the one it points to.

In this case, `&xc + 1` points to memory that lies outside the allocation of `xc`. You cannot read or write to this location and expect any kind of predictable result. Note that it is actually a valid pointer -- you *are* allowed to point "one-past-the-end" of an allocation, provided you never dereference that address.

To explain what's actually happening in *your* case: your variables are being pushed onto the stack, and the stack memory extends in the direction of lower addresses. It appears your compiler didn't bother to unwind the stack after the original `x` went out of scope. Alternatively, multiple values of 532 might have been initialized in memory, or in a register, and the value you're reading might not be the one that was stored at `x`. All this said, even this program on your computer with your compiler does not guarantee this behavior.

- The original variable `x` could be optimized away by the compiler completely because it is not used.
- The value of `xc` is uninitialized. Its location (if any) on the stack is not guaranteed. Even though `x` had additional scope, the compiler is not required to push and pop stack locations if it doesn't want to.
- The compiler is not required to understand that you're aliasing `x` via `xc` because, as already mentioned such behavior is not defined.